# Assessing surrogacy for 2 treatment effects

Tags: bayesian, correlation, predictive-models, clinical-trials, surrogate

I'm interested in analyzing whether an intervention's effect on an outcome, *X*, qualifies as a surrogate for its effect on another outcome, *Y*.

By the end of the analysis, I would like to have:

**A)** An estimate of the slope (for every change in X, we can expect this much change in Y).

**B)** An estimate of R-squared (how much of the variance in Y is explained by X).

**C)** The surrogate threshold effect (a decrease in X by this much would correspond to a 95% prediction interval that excludes the null).

An example of what I'd want to emulate: https://www.thelancet.com/journals/landia/article/PIIS2213-8587(18)30314-0/

Now, onto the data and approaches I've tried:

Suppose I have a dataset of N trials containing treatment effects on *X* and *Y*, the standard errors of these treatment effects, and the within-trial correlation of treatment effects on *X* and *Y*. A simulated example:

```
#Load foreach and data.table
require("foreach")
require("data.table")

#Sequence over range of (somewhat) plausible surrogate treatment effects "stes"
stes <- seq(-0.5, 0.5, 0.05)

#Run a loop over stes
tes <- foreach(ste = stes,
        counter_id = 1:length(stes), #Add a loop counter as a trial id
        .combine = "rbind") %do% {
          
          #Sample some amount of error from 0.1 to 1
          error <- sample(seq(0.1, 1, 0.1), 1)
          
          #Simulate a distribution of surrogate treatment effects
          #giving rise to the observed treatment effect in this trial
          surrogate_dist <- rnorm(n = 1000,
                                  mean = ste, #With a given mean
                                  sd = error) #With a given standard deviation
          
          #Sample some amount of within-trial correlation of treatment effects from 0.1 to 1
          rho <- sample(seq(0.1, 0.8, 0.1), 1)
          
          #Simulate a distribution of true treatment effects
          #giving rise to the observed treatment effect in this trial
          true_dist <- (rho * surrogate_dist) + sqrt(1 - rho*rho) * rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 0, sd = error)
          
          #Create a data.table representing this trial
          data.table(trial_id = counter_id,
                     surrogate_te = mean(surrogate_dist),
                     true_te = mean(true_dist),
                     surrogate_sete = sd(surrogate_dist),
                     true_sete = sd(true_dist),
                     intra_cor = rho)
        }
```

My **initial impulse** based on previous literature (https://10.0.3.233/jamainternmed.2021.5726 among other examples) was to just run a weighted linear regression, with the weights being equal to the inverse of the sum of the variances of treatment effects (such that we let more precise estimates shape our results):

```
#Run weighted least squares with weights equal to the precision of the observed
#treatment effect
#Run weighted least squares with weights equal to the precision of the observed
#treatment effect
weighted_model <- lm(data = tes, 
                     formula = true_te ~ surrogate_te, 
                     weights = 1/(surrogate_sete^2 + true_sete^2))
```

The 2 problems with this are (I think) that: first, it does not take within-trial correlation into account at all. Second, it does not take into account the uncertainty of the treatment effects (to my understanding, it only uses their relative weights to shape the estimates but treats them as "certain"/"known").

Other approaches I've tried include:

**1)** Incorporating error in the treatment effects using the `se` and `me` functions of `brms` (similar to: https://bookdown.org/ajkurz/Statistical_Rethinking_recoded/missing-data-and-other-opportunities.html):

```
#Model 1
m1 <- brm(data = tes,
          prior = prior(normal(0, 1), class = "b"),
          cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1,
          formula = true_te | se(true_sete) ~ me(surrogate_te, surrogate_sete)
          )
```

But this would not account for within-trial correlation.

**2)** Using a multivariate normal in `brms` and modeling the correlation between the residuals (similar to: https://solomonkurz.netlify.app/blog/2019-02-16-bayesian-correlations-let-s-talk-options/):

```
#Model 2
m2 <- brm(data = tes,
                prior = prior(normal(0, 1), class = "Intercept"),
                cores = parallel::detectCores() - 1,
                formula = bf(true_te | se(true_sete) ~ 1) +
            bf(surrogate_te | se(surrogate_sete) ~ 1) +
            set_rescor(TRUE)
          )
```

But again, this would not account for within-trial correlation.

**3)** Reframing the problem and viewing the two types of outcomes (surrogate and true) as being random effects nested within trials (inspired by Paul Buerkner's reply here: https://discourse.mc-stan.org/t/brms-multivariate-meta-analysis-syntax/6801):

```
#Convert tes to long format first
tes_long <- data.table(
  te = tes[, .(c(true_te, surrogate_te)), by = trial_id][[2]],
  se = tes[, .(c(true_sete, surrogate_sete)), by = trial_id][[2]],
  outcome = rep(c("True", "Surrogate"), times = nrow(tes)),
  trial_id = rep(tes$trial_id, each = 2),
  intra_cor =  rep(tes$intra_cor, each = 2)
)

#Create a variance-covariance matrix
cov_matrix <- matrix(nrow = nrow(tes_long),
                     ncol = nrow(tes_long)
)

#Fill up the diagonals with the variance for surrogate and true treatment effects
diag(cov_matrix) <- tes_long$se^2

#Calculate and fill in the covariance of all-cause and HF hospitalizations for each trial
for(i in  1:uniqueN(tes_long$trial_id)) {
  cov_matrix[2*i, (2*i) - 1] <- tes_long[trial_id == i, intra_cor][1]*sqrt(cov_matrix[(2*i) - 1, (2*i) - 1])*sqrt(cov_matrix[2*i, 2*i])
  cov_matrix[(2*i) - 1, 2*i] <- tes_long[trial_id == i, intra_cor][1]*sqrt(cov_matrix[(2*i) - 1, (2*i) - 1])*sqrt(cov_matrix[2*i, 2*i])
}

#Convert NAs to 0
cov_matrix[is.na(cov_matrix)] <- 0

#Model 3
m3 <- brm(data = tes_long,
          data2 = list(cov_matrix = cov_matrix),
          prior =
            c(prior(constant(1), class = "sigma")),
          cores = 16,
          formula = te ~ 
            0 + #No global intercept
            outcome + #A separate intercept for each of the 2 outcomes
            (0 + outcome|trial_id) + #Nest the 2 outcomes within their trials
            fcor(cov_matrix) #Pass the covariance matrix
)
```

Any help for which of these models (if any) are most suitable would be greatly appreciated! Pardon the lengthy post.

Comment: An important step here is to ask yourself why you need a surrogate for a surrogate. In the first paper you cite, albuminuria is a surrogate for kidney dysfunction which is a surrogate for patient-important outcomes such as need for dialysis, hospitalization, and death.

Comment: Oh, I only meant the attached paper as a methodological example. For my particular analysis, both are clinical outcomes but one is (generally regarded as being) more important than the other.

Comment: You should note that this, and other attempts, to reduce the CKD diagnostic criteria have been fairly unsuccessful. This has largely to do with the attitudes of the experts considering the value of the proposed surrogate endpoint. That said, any discussion on the point should include extensive statistical analysis.

Comment: The post's title is assessing surrogacy for *2 treatment effects* but I don't see how that is explained in the post. The point of a valid surrogate is that it predicts the endpoint reliably *irrespective of other exogenous factors* such as randomized treatment assignment.

Comment: Lastly, I think this notational usage and definitions are a little sloppy. Rather you should speak of a primary outcome, which you may call $Y$. $X$ we typically reserve for input variables, and a treatment assignment seems to be a consideration. Therefore, notationally your surrogate could be, say, $S$ or $U$.

Comment: I vote to close this. I suggest you remove your codes and consider your approach more carefully. You speak of performing an inverse variance weighted meta-analysis, but you complain of "within trial correlation". What are you defining "within trial correlation" to be and how should it impact your analysis? If the treatment effect is heterogeneous among the population then you can't do a meta analysis and you have a crappy surrogate. There is a lot of literature on meta-analysis. Bayesian won't save you on this.